# Stability considerations for a special type of LTV systems

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, linear-control

I have been considering the stability of an (nonautonomous) LTV system $\dot{x} = A(t)x$ of the form

$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_{1}\\ \dot{x}_{2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-a(t) & -b(t)\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\x_{2}\end{bmatrix}$,

where we know that $a(t), b(t) > 0$ and both $a(t), b(t)$ are both continuous, differentiable, and bounded. By simulating such a system, it clearly seems to be stable, but I do not quite see how to prove that this is true and which restrictions that apply. By computing the eigenvalues we get

$\lambda_{1,2}(t) = \frac{-a(t) \pm \sqrt{a(t)^{2} - 4b(t)}}{2} < 0\; \forall\; t $,

with the restrictions we placed on $a(t), b(t)$. However, as emphasized by, e.g., Khalil (Nonlinear Systems (2002), Section 4.6), the eigenvalues of $A$ cannot be used to assert stability of such a system. If we instead fix $a, b$, then, by the same eigenvalues, the (autonomous) LTI system $\dot{x} = Ax$ is stable as long as $a, b > 0$.

I know that asserting the stability of general LTV systems is difficult, and from what I can see, most of the literature refer to numerical integration to find the transition matrix of the system. But is there really no other way to discuss the system shown above? The most "obvious" alternative that comes to mind is to find an appropriate Lyapunov function candidate, but I do not seem to be able to come up with a good candidate (?)

Comment: Do you have an explicit form for the function $a$ and $b$? If not what properties do they have? Continuous? Differentiable? Bounded?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I do not have an explicit form for a(t) and b(t) but I do assume they are both continuous, differentiable, and bounded. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Then, you will have to build a Lyapunov function. Check robust/LPV analysis and control.

Comment: Take $a(t)=b(t)=\exp(−t)>0$ which is bounded, continuous and differentiable. Then $x_2\rightarrow\infty$ for some initial conditions. So you will need more conditions for stability of this system.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned that you do not know beforehand the actual trajectories of $a$ and $b$, then no LTV method will be applicable.

A possible way is to treat those time-varying coefficients as time-varying uncertainties/parameters which both take values in some intervals; e.g. $a\in[a^-,a^+]$ and $b\in[b^-,b^+]$.

A first possible approach is to check whether the system is quadratically stable, that is, whether the function $V(x)=x^TPx$, $P=P^T\succ0$, is a Lyapunov function for the system. In the present case, this is equivalent to the feasibility of the following Linear Matrix Inequalities

$$A(a,b)^TP+PA(a,b)\prec0$$ for all $(a,b)\in\{a^-,a^+\}\times\{b^-,b^+\}$.

Depending on the bounds you may try to solve for that but such a matrix $P$ may not exist. The reasons are we are restricting ourselves to quadratic Lyapunov functions and that are allowed for a quite general classes of signals, including discontinuous ones.

The next step is to look at a robust stability criterion where you can try to find a Lyapunov function of the form $V(x)=x^TP(a,b)x$, $P(a,b)=P(a,b)^T\succ0$. This would lead to a stability condition of the form

$$\dot{a}\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial a}+\dot{b}\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial b}+A(a,b)^TP(a,b)+P(a,b)A(a,b)\prec 0$$

which must hold for all the values for $(a,b)$ and all values for $(\dot{a},\dot{b})$. This is much more complicated to consider and numerical methods are often used to check such conditions. The advantage of this approach is that we can capture information on the derivative of the parameters and it can be proven that if the system with frozen eigenvalues is stable, then it will remain stable provided that the rates of variation of the parameter is small enough.

In other words, the stability of the frozen LTV/LPV systems implies that of the LTV/LPV system provided that the rates of variation of the parameters are sufficiently small.

Comment: If the possible values for $(a,b)$ can be constrained by some convex set then it would be sufficient (but not always necessary) to only check the "corner points" of the convex set when checking $$A(a,b)^\top P + P\,A(a,b)\prec0$$ since any $A(a,b)$ can be obtained from linear combination $A(a,b)$ evaluated at the corner points. And if the corner points yield are negative definite result then every linear combination would as well.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I am already only checking at the vertex points and it is necessary and sufficient to check at the extremal point for the validity of the LMI over the whole range of values for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. At the first read through I missinterpretted it as intervals instead of sets. Though, it can be noted that it is not necessary to satisfy that inequality at all vertex points. For example when $a$ and $b$ are correlated. But one could get more tighter bounds by using vertex points that form a tighter convex set around the actually allowed values.

Comment: Yes but here $a$ $b$ are independent from each other.

Comment: The question does not explicitly state that they are independent. For example it might be that $b(t) = c\,a(t)$.

Comment: I am talking that they are independent in my reply. Moreover, the OP said the signals are not known so the likelihood that they are independent is pretty high. Even if they were, the fact that we do not know them will force us to consider independent.

Comment: What does "small enough" mean precisely? Seems like this still requires a Lyapunov function in the first place.

Comment: @SampleTime Small enough means sufficiently small in this context. One way is to assume constant parameters and prove the stability using e.g. a parameter-dependent Lyapunov function and then use perturbation results to obtain the stability of the LTV system for sufficiently slowly-varying parameters.

Comment: @KBS Yes but how small is "sufficiently small". The point is that such a statement is not really useful if no explicit bound can be provided. Because without such bound it doesn't really matter how small the variation is, it might always be too large.

Comment: @SampleTime It is not because there is no explicit form that it is useless. The fact that the stability of an LTI system implies that of an LTV is already interesting. It is also a case by case analysis and this is the reason why there is no good explicit form. There may be some but I would expect them to be very conservative. In the present context, they can be estimated by building a Lyapunov function and solving a bunch of SDP problems which is not too difficult due to the simplicity of the problem.

Comment: @KBS Yes, as I said you still need a Lyapunov function. I agree this is interesting but I fail to see how the properties of the LTI matter here if at the end we need a Lyapunov function anyway.

Comment: @SampleTime This is just an example, it is possible to use other methods such as robust analysis methods for systems in LFT form, a commutator calculus approach, a trajectory-based approach or even an ad-hoc one to solve that problem. The issue is that they may be complicated to use. Finally, I was mentioning that result for completeness so that the OP knows what they are dealing with. The answer was not directed to anyone else.  Finally, I have never said to use that statement but rather to focus on the LMI conditions which already involve the bounds on the derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

The time varying system you propose can be unstable depending the particular choice for $a(t)$ and $b(t)$. In order to make a counter example a little simpler to analyse I am ignoring that $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ both need to be continuous. Namely the following time varying system is unstable

$$
A(t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
A_1 & \text{if }\ (t\!\mod 5\pi/4) < \pi \\
A_2 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right. \tag{1}
$$

$$
A_1 =
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.2 & -0.25 \\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
A_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.8 & -4 \\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{2}
$$

In case my notation is unclear, $A(t)$ alternates between being equal to $A_1$ and $A_2$, where $A_1$ is active for $\pi$ time units and $A_2$ is active for $\pi/4$ time units.

When $A(t)$ is periodic with period $T$, such that $A(t+T) = A(t)\ \forall\ t \in \mathbb{R}$ then the stability can be determined by looking at the [state transition matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix) $\Phi(\tau+T,\tau)$ (with $\tau$ any constant real value). Namely, this state transition repeats every $T$ time units and thus one can do a discrete time stability analysis using the eigenvalues of $\Phi(\tau+T,\tau)$. For discrete time stability analysis of a linear time invariant system the absolute value of the eigenvalues needs lie withing the unit circle, instead of negative real part for the continuous time case.

When considering the example above, or any linear time varying system with piecewise constant dynamics, the state transition matrix from the start till the end of one active period of $A_i$ (with $i$ either $1$ or $2$) can be obtained using [matrix exponentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)

$$
\Phi(\tau_i+T_i,\tau_i) = e^{A_i\,T_i}, \tag{3}
$$

with $\tau_i$ the start of the active mode and $T_i$ the time length of the active mode (such that $T = T_1 + T_2$). A possible $\Phi(\tau+T,\tau)$ can be obtained using

$$
\Phi(\tau+T,\tau) = \Phi(\tau_1+T_1,\tau_1)\,\Phi(\tau_2+T_2,\tau_2) = e^{A_1\,T_1}\,e^{A_2\,T_2}. \tag{4}
$$

When substituting $(2)$ and the corresponding active periods $T_i$ into $(4)$ and evaluating the absolute value of the eigenvalues yields $|\lambda_1| \approx 0.13$ and $|\lambda_2| \approx 2.18$. It can be noted that $|\lambda_2| > 1$, so $\lambda_2$ lies outside of the unit circle and thus it can be concluded that a linear time varying system using $(1)$ would be unstable.

---

It is probably also possible to modify my counter example slightly to obtain a counter example which does have that $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ both are continuous. For example instead of instantaneously switching, having a quick linear interpolation between the two around the switching times. However, the evaluation of the state transition matrix then becomes a little more complicated.

---

The best tool for analyzing the stability of a linear time varying system in general would probably be Lyapunov functions. For example by looking for a, potentially time varying, common quadratic Lyapunov function

$$
V(x) = x^\top P(t)\,x, \tag{5}
$$

with $\alpha_1 \prec P(t) \prec \alpha_2\ \forall\ t$, where $0 < \alpha_1 \leq \alpha_2$ and $\alpha_2$ bounded, and the time derivative of $(7)$ should satisfy

$$
\dot{V}(x) = x^\top \left(A^\top\!(t) P(t) + \dot{P}(t) + P(t)\,A(t)\right) x \leq 0 \tag{6}
$$

and thus $A^\top\!(t) P(t) + \dot{P}(t) + P(t)\,A(t)$ should be a negative definite matrix for all $t$.

For the general time varying case I am not aware of structured ways of looking for such $P(t)$. However, when limiting $P(t)$ to be constant one can look for a solution using [linear matrix inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality). Namely, the previous requirements are equivalent to the following inequalities

\begin{align}
P &\succ 0, \\
A^\top\!(t)\,P + P\,A(t) &\preceq 0,\ \forall\ t.
\end{align}

One way to look for such a $P$ could be taking a lot of samples of $A(t)$ using different $t$ values (or as KBS mentioned, only the vertex points obtained from the extremas of $a(t)$ and $b(t)$). Use those evaluated values of $A(t)$ to construct a set of linear matrix inequalities, which can be attempted to be solved using a computer.

I suspect that not every stable linear time varying system can be proven to be stable using a constant common quadratic Lyapunov function. More relevant analysis tools can also be found in the sub-field of hybrid system, using topics like minimum dwell time.

Comment: LaSalle cannot be used for time-varying systems. It is only available for time-invariant/homogeneous systems.

Comment: @KBS good point. I have removed that sentence. Instead of LaSalle one could probably still use Barbalat’s lemma.

Comment: Yes, but that does not solve certain other problems. The main issue here is one eigenvalue may approach zero asymptotically or that Barbalat's lemma asks for extra conditions to be satisfied. I would just consider uniform exponential stability here for simplicity.